# Google Colab session crashes after using all available RAM

Tags: google-colaboratory

Google Colab session crashes after using all available RAM when loading a CSV file consisting of 1,00,000 records into a dataframe. Please see the logs below. I am using TPS runtime.

**Error message** - Your session crashed after using all available RAM.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEpnK.png)

Comment: Someone answered that here [change the Runtime as GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59857326/14521954)