# Google Colab - Your session crashed for an unknown reason

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

> Your session crashed for an unknown reason

when I run the following cell in Google Colab:

```
from keras import backend as K
if 'tensorflow' == K.backend():
  import tensorflow as tf
  from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
  config = tf.ConfigProto()
  config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
  config.gpu_options.visible_device_list = "0"
  set_session(tf.Session(config=config))
```

I receive this message since I have uploaded two data sets to google drive.

Does anyone know this message and can give me some advice?
Many thanks for every hint.

**Update:**
[image]I always receive the message

**Update**
I have removed the data sets from Google Drive, but the session is still crashing.

Comment: Has nodbody an idea? Please help, I'm already desperate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Colab is crashing because you are trying to Run Code related to `GPU` with `Runtime` as `CPU`.

The execution is successful if you change the Runtime as GPU. Steps for the same are mentioned below:

Runtime -> Change Runtime -> GPU (Select from dropdown).

Please find the Working code in [Github Gist](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/rmothukuru/816d957d9bac6bab849459629d9af458/so_59703866.ipynb).

Answer (score 0):

Just a side note: sometimes you may want to reinstall an litle older version of the related module (see from the error log). It works for me in a case.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when the expected device and the actual device are different.

For example, if you run the code that is written with torch_xla, which is for TPU training, on the GPU (cuda) then the Colab will return you this error.

It is really tricky since it does not give you an actual debugging message, etc, which makes you hard to find what is the actual problem.